# Convert unmanaged C++ pointer to an object to a managed C# object

Tags: c#, c++, .net, pinvoke, marshalling

I have an unmanaged static library (.dll) written on C++:

```
// This is a personal academic project. Dear PVS-Studio, please check it.
// PVS-Studio Static Code Analyzer for C, C++ and C#: http://www.viva64.com
#include "program.h"

struct MyData
{
    int32_t index;
    char* name;
    //uint8_t* data;
};

extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport) MyData* GetMyData()
    {
        MyData* ms = new MyData();
        ms->index = 5;
        ms->name = "Happy string";
        //ms->data = new uint8_t[5] { 4, 8, 16, 32, 64 };
        return ms;
    }
}
```

The 'GetMyData' method returns pointer to 'MyData' object.

I imported this library into C# projeсt using 'PInvoke' and called the 'GetMyData' method.

```
// This is a personal academic project. Dear PVS-Studio, please check it.
// PVS-Studio Static Code Analyzer for C, C++ and C#: http://www.viva64.com
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public class MyData
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public Int32 index;

    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public String name;

    //[FieldOffset(8)]
    //public Byte[] data;
};

class Program
{
    [DllImport("TestCpp.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetMyData();

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Call 'GetMyData' method and get structure from pointer using marshaling.
        var ptr = GetMyData();
        var ms = Marshal.PtrToStructure<MyData>(ptr);

        // Print my data into console
        var str = ms.index.ToString();
        str += ", " + ms.name;
        //str += ", [" + string.Join(", ", ms.data) + "]";
        Console.WriteLine(str);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

This code works fine, but if I uncomment the using of 'data' member of 'MyData' type (in C++ and C# code), I will get exception in C# code on this line:

> var ms = Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr);
>
> Error:
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeArrayTypeMismatchException:
>   'Mismatch has occurred between the runtime type of the array and the
>   sub type recorded in the metadata.'

As I understand the offset argument in the 'FieldOffset' attribute - it's a shift in bytes in unmanaged memory during convert unmanaged C++ object to managed C# object.

Field 'index' has 4 bytes size because it's 32-bit type.

Field 'name' is pointer to char array. For 32-bit architecture it's also 32-bit number (4 bytes).

Which offset in 'FieldOffset' attribute i need to use for 'data' field?

Comment: Due to the peculiarities of the implementation my project, there is no way to use C++/CLI.

Comment: You are getting the error from the String name.  A string in c++ is really a byte[] in c# which is a pointer to an array.  So use Intptr name.

Comment: You don't need FieldOffset any more once you fix name to be IntPtr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it easily... As suggested by Ðаn do it manually or

```
[FieldOffset(8)]
public IntPtr _data;

public byte[] GetData()
{
    // YOU MUST FREE _data C-side! You can't use
    // C++ delete C#-side
    var bytes = new byte[5];
    Marshal.Copy(_data, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    return bytes;
}
```

There is another (little) problem here: I'm against using `LayoutKind.Explicit` unless you really need it. Start with `LayoutKind.Sequential` and see if it is enough. Using `LayoutKind.Sequential` you'll be more ready to switch from 32 to 64 bits, because the struct will be stretched for the size of the pointers.

Comment: Thanks, it's worked for me, but the argument 'unmanagedType' had to be replaced from 'UnmanagedType.LPArray' to 'UnmanagedType.ByValArray' for correct work. With 'UnmanagedType.LPArray' i get exception.

Comment: @IvanKishchenko No it doesn't work with ByValArray. Unaccept the response so I can delete it please.

Comment: I Unaccept the response as you asked, but it's works for me fine.

Comment: @IvanKishchenko It can be random... ByValArray is for when you have `struct MyStruct { uint8_t bytes[5]; }`

Comment: @Ðаn Rarely introducing another project to your solution, in a syntax you don't know (C++/CLI) will make something "easier". While you do probably  like very much C++/CLI, you are probably one of the few persons on the earth that like it :-) (otherwise you would find more questions about it on SO). I Consider C++/CLI to be the "nuclear option", not the first line of offense in a pinvoke problem.

Comment: @Ðаn, I use Mono for cross-platform. C++/CLI not variant.